# How can I use authentication on docker HTML report?

Tags: docker, jmeter

How can I use authentication on docker HTML report?

for example :- https://localhost:3000

is my docker run url.. so how can i authenticate this

Answer (score 0):

From what you are explaining I understand you would like to add some form of authentication to a web application that happens to run in docker. I would suggest maybe try get it running first without docker on a Linux server using the same distro as the base image that you are using in your Dockerfile. So for example if you are using a Ubuntu 16.04 image that I suggest that you try set this up on a Linux server.

You can add LDAP or HTTP auth if you setup Nginx as a reverse proxy to your application. This would also allow you to be able to access the application on port 443 instead of https://url:3000

Here are some resources on using nginx for authentication.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I would suggest you change the tag on this question to #nginx or #ubuntu instead. What kind of authentication would you like to add?